# How to delete angular generated element in DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have ran into a wall with this. This is my delete function from my mainController.

```
$scope.delete = function($posts) {
    $http.delete('/api/posts/' + $posts._id)
        .success(function(data) {
            // delete element from DOM
            // on success I want to delete the post I'm clicking on.
        });
```

And here is the template where I load my data with angular.

```
<div id="post-stream">
    <h4>Chirp Feed</h4>
    <div class="post" ng-repeat="post in posts.results | orderBy:'created_at':true" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
        <button ng-click="delete(post)" ng-show="authenticated" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right remove">x</button>
        <p>{{post.text}}</p>
        <small>Posted by @{{post.created_by}}</small>
        <small class="pull-right">{{post.created_at | date:"h:mma 'on' MMM d, y"}}</small>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can delete the posts in my database but I can't figure out how to delete the element I'm clicking on.

Comment: you would just want to remove the post from your post.results collection. That will automatically remove it from the dom.

Comment: If you try to manipulate the dom directly you are usually doing something wrong with angular.

Comment: That's what it does right now but I would have to reload the page to see the changes. I want to delete the element on click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see in your html code, you have a variable `$scope.posts.results`.

ng-repeat gives you on each element a variable `$index` that you can use to delete an element

add this `$index` into your html :

```
 ng-click="delete(post, $index)"
```

And then, into your controller, delete the element from your array

```
$scope.delete = function($posts, postIndex) {    
    $http.delete('/api/posts/' + $posts._id)
          .success(function(data) {
               $scope.posts.results.splice(postIndex, 1);
          });

};
```

then, ng-repeat will remove your node from the DOM. You don't need to manipulate the DOM directly.

Comment: awesome!!!! it worked. I have to wait 3 minutes at this time before I can check your solution. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks to you too, I didn't know about `ng-class-odd="'odd'"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button ng-click="delete(post)" ng-show="authenticated" class="btn btn-
```

This is what I ended up doing.

```
$scope.delete = function($posts, postIndex) {    
        $http.delete('/api/posts/' + $posts._id)
              .success(function(data) {
                 var index = $scope.posts.results.indexOf(data);
                   $scope.posts.results.splice(index, 1);
              });

    };
```